# MySQL: comparing multiple rows from a joint table to the primary table using NOT IN?

Tags: mysql, list, join

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS e.*
FROM exercises e
LEFT JOIN exercise_targetedmuscles em ON em.exerciseID = e.exerciseID
WHERE (em.targetedMuscleID NOT IN(15,16,17,14,3,12,9,8,7,18,4,2) AND em.isPrimary = 1)
GROUP BY e.exerciseID
ORDER BY e.name ASC
```

I want to make sure that **none** of the targetted muscles of the exercise (of which there may be many) are in the list "(15,16,17,14,3,12,9,8,7,18,4,2)", however this only checks the first one it finds. How can I check all of the matching rows from **exercise_targetedmuscles** instead of just the first?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS e.*
FROM exercises e
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
      FROM  exercise_targetedmuscles em
        WHERE  em.exerciseID = e.exerciseID
                AND   em.targetedMuscleID IN(15,16,17,14,3,12,9,8,7,18,4,2)
        AND em.isPrimary = 1
)
GROUP BY e.exerciseID
ORDER BY e.name ASC
```

Comment: thank you so much! that's an awesome way to put it. thanks again for the helpful knowledge.
one very minor change i had to make was adding "em" after the second "FROM" to give it the alias. otherwise, flawless.